# user datetime setting as GMT, how to convert date to their localized setting?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, gmt

In my users setting I have a dropdown with all the GMT dates for the user to select.

In c#, how would I convert a datetime stored in the database to their GMT time?

The time stored in the database is the servers time.

Comment: In what format do you store your user's time zone data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET 3.5+, you can store the system time zone identifier with the user (you can get those from `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones`) and use `TimeZoneInfo` to convert between time zones:

```
// In a User class that has a string timeZoneId field (for example)
public DateTime GetLocalDateTime(DateTime originalDate) {
    DateTime utcDate      = TimeZoneInfo.Local.ConvertToUtc(originalDate);
    TimeZone userTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(this.timeZoneId);
    return   TimeZone.ConvertTime(utcDate, userTimeZone);
}
```

In .NET 2.0, you're limited to the older `TimeZone` class which is only available for the local system. You don't automatically get daylight savings information for the user, so you'd have to store that yourself alongside the basic GMT/UTC offset.

```
// In a User class that has a double utcOffset field (for example)
public DateTime GetLocalDateTime(DateTime originalDate) {
    DateTime utcDate = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(originalDate);
    return utcDate.AddHours(this.utcOffset);
}

// Usage
DateTime localDate = user.GetLocalDateTime(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're storing the GMT difference for each user? I.e. 0 or +1 or -6, etc?

```
// Get your DateTime to convert
DateTime databaseDateTime = DateTime.Now;
double userGmtOffset = 1;

// Get the GMT time of the database time
int hoursOffset = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(databaseDateTime).Hours;
DateTime gmtDateTime = databaseDateTime.AddHours((double)(0 - hoursOffset));
DateTime userDateTime = gmtDateTime.AddHours(userGmtOffset);
```

Comment: I've made some changes so this should do the trick now... Although I'm not sure regarding what happens with daylight savings. So I look forward to feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime. IT includes all the functionality you need.