# Need to get Time by TimeZoneId

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

I need to get time by TimeZoneId. I have googled but found TimeZoneInfo class and that have particular method to get time by TimeZoneId. TimeZoneInfo class only supported in .net framework 3.5 but I am using .Net Framework 2.0.

Can anyone tell me how can I accomplish this in .net framework 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: I think this has been answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637144/user-datetime-setting-as-gmt-how-to-convert-date-to-their-localized-setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution really is to upgrade to .NET 3.5.  That's what we did when we needed the functionality.

If you cannot do that, you're going to have to read the relevent data from the registry.  Although its reasonably well documented you're still going to have to write code to correctly do the conversions which is no mean task.  Get Reflector out and have a look at the implementation of the TimeZoneInfo class in System.Core.dll version 3.5 and you'll see what I mean.

I'm not aware of any third party libraries that work like TimeZoneInfo